# PHP show table from record with same id

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I want to return to the user a table that shows his orders but when a user orders one product the table is ok but in the moment that orders 2 product they get 2 lines with the same ID but different ProductID same total price.

[image]

```
$email = strval($_SESSION["email"]); 
$TabellaOrdini = "SELECT DISTINCT ordini.IDOrdini, clienti.Indirizzo,       
                        clienti.Nome, clienti.Cognome, ordini.StatoConsegna, 
                        prodotti.Descrizione, ordini.TotaleOrdine, 
                        pacco.IDProdotti, pacco.Quantita
                FROM (((clienti NATURAL JOIN ordini) 
                    JOIN pacco ON ordini.IDPacco = pacco.IDPacco) 
                    JOIN prodotti ON pacco.IDProdotti = prodotti.IDProdotti)
                WHERE  clienti.IDClienti = ordini.IDClienti  
                AND clienti.Email = '$email' 
                ORDER BY ordini.IDOrdini";

$CheckOrdini =   "SELECT insertphpordini.IDOrdini, 
                    concat(insertphpordini.Descrizione,' x ',insertphpordini.Quantita) AS Risultato
                FROM insertphpordini
                WHERE insertphpordini.Email = '$email' 
                AND insertphpordini.IDOrdini IN
                    ( SELECT insertphpordini.IDOrdini 
                      FROM insertphpordini
                      GROUP BY insertphpordini.IDOrdini
                      HAVING COUNT(IDOrdini)>1
                    )";

$result = $conn -> query($TabellaOrdini);

$result2 = $conn -> query($CheckOrdini);
  
echo "<table id='customers'>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan=7>Ordini</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><b>IDOrdine</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>Nome</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>Cognome</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>Indirizzo</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>Stato Consegna</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>Prodotto</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>Totale Ordine</b></td>";
        
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> $row[IDOrdini]</td>";
    echo "<td> $row[Nome]</td>";
    echo "<td> $row[Cognome] </td>";
    echo "<td> $row[Indirizzo] </td>";
    echo "<td> $row[StatoConsegna] </td>";
    echo "<td> $row[Descrizione] / $row[Quantita]</td> ";
    echo "<td> $row[TotaleOrdine]€ </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
      
echo "</table>";
```

the query $TabellaOrdini get all values from a user whit that email and the query $CheckOrdini get only the values with the same ID and concat the Description and quantity as Risultato.

My goal is that is possible to have 1 order with 1 ID and in Product(row 6 from left of the table) have "ProductName1/Quantity1, ProductName2/Quantity2"

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine values from multiple rows into a single column.

```
$TabellaOrdini = "SELECT ordini.IDOrdini, clienti.Indirizzo, clienti.Nome, clienti.Cognome, ordini.StatoConsegna,
                         prodotti.Descrizione, ordini.TotaleOrdine, GROUP_CONCAT(pacco.IDProdotti, '/', pacco.Quantita) AS Prodotto
                  FROM clienti
                  NATURAL JOIN ordini
                  JOIN pacco ON ordini.IDPacco = pacco.IDPacco
                  JOIN prodotti ON pacco.IDProdotti = prodotti.IDProdotti
                  WHERE  clienti.IDClienti = ordini.IDClienti  AND clienti.Email = '$email' ORDER BY ordini.IDOrdini
                  GROUP BY ordini.IDOdini";
```

It's also not necessary to group your joins with `()`.

And you should stop substituting variables directly into SQL, and instead use prepared statements with `bind_param()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use better display of Orders with Order ID, Customer details, Date in one row along with a drop down with all detailed products and quantities. This way you are not limited with tabular display option.
Else, you can use **GROUP_CONCAT** with **ordini.IDOrdini** (your OrderID) and display products as *"product01, product02, product03"* for same *Order01* for instance.

Here some link for ***data-tables with child-rows*** :

*https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html*

Or you can **ajax** it out for large child product sets :

*https://datatables.net/blog/2017-03-31*

**NOTE:** Please ensure PHP security and try to follow some design pattern for a clean code. Look for Database Object and Binding input parameters with ***$conn->prepare*** [*https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php*]